# Nested arrays of objects and v-for

Tags: vue.js

Well, this problem has me stumped... Having a bit of trouble getting nested for-loop data to show up:

```
<div v-if = "private.folders!=null" v-for="folder in private.folders">
{{folder.name}}
    <div v-for="check in folder.checks">
        {{check.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the data that I'm trying to use looks like this:

```
folders [Array]
-object [this is a single 'folder']
--name
--checks [array] [each folder has this array]
---[object] [the actual 'check' object]
----[name]
```

The outer loop works just fine, and returns the data I expect. However, check.name doesn't return anything, and there are no errors in the console. Is it possible to do nested for-loops like this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I tested you template, it's works.

```js
 new Vue({
  el: '#sample',
  data: {
    private: {
      folders : [{
          name : 'folder1',
          checks : [
            { name : 'check1.1' },
            { name : 'check1.2' }
          ]
        },
        {
          name : 'folder2',
          checks : [
            { name : 'check2.1' },
            { name : 'check2.2' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<div id="sample">
  <div v-if = "private.folders!=null" v-for="folder in private.folders">
  {{folder.name}}
      <div v-for="check in folder.checks">
          {{check.name}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it didn't work for me, though i used table and not div

Comment: how use index (without reset) in nested?

Comment: Avoid using v-for and v-if in the same element

Comment: You can only combine `v-if` and `v-for` if you want to evaluate wether or not to render the `v-for`. This is because `v-if` is evaluated **before** `v-for`. So if the `v-if` evaluates to false, `v-for` will not be executed.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you might set it up with HTML table:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#sample',
  data: {
    private: {
      folders : [{
          name : 'folder1',
          checks : [
            { name : 'check1.1' },
            { name : 'check1.2' }
          ]
        },
        {
          name : 'folder2',
          checks : [
            { name : 'check2.1' },
            { name : 'check2.2' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<div id="sample">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Folder</th>
    <th>Checks</th>
    <th>Checks</th>
  </tr>
  <tr v-if = "private.folders!=null" v-for="folder in private.folders">
  <td><b>{{folder.name}}</b></td>
      <td v-for="check in folder.checks">
         {{check.name}}
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not supposed to conditional render on the same line your are declaring  the v-for

Comment: @CristianoSoleti incorrect; you just need to realize that the `v-if` will be evaluated before `v-for`. If you're not aware of this (like OP) this might lead to unexpected results.

Comment: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-use-v-if-with-v-for.html @xorinzor