# Iterating through group by results

Tags: vue.js

I have to iterate through groups and inside groups I need to iterate for every group in its own.

this is the response I get:

```
{
    "message": "",
    "status": "success",
    "response": {
        "Te dhenat e Klientit": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "specification": "Personal Accidents",
                "header": "Te dhenat e Klientit",
                "item": "Veprimtaria",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "specification": "Personal Accidents",
                "header": "Te dhenat e Klientit",
                "item": "Numri i Siguruarve",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "specification": "Personal Accidents",
                "header": "Te dhenat e Klientit",
                "item": "Mosha Mesatare",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "specification": "Personal Accidents",
                "header": "Te dhenat e Klientit",
                "item": "Tjere",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ],
        "Shuma e Sigurimit": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "specification": "Personal Accidents",
                "header": "Shuma e Sigurimit",
                "item": "Objekti i Sigurimit",
                "type": "list"
            }
        ],
        "Mbulimet e Kerkuara": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "specification": "Personal Accidents",
                "header": "Mbulimet e Kerkuara",
                "item": "Mbulimi",
                "type": "list"
            }
        ],
        "Shenime": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "specification": "Personal Accidents",
                "header": "Shenime",
                "item": "Shenime",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ],
        "Primi total per Person": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "specification": "Personal Accidents",
                "header": "Primi total per Person",
                "item": "Primi Neto",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "specification": "Personal Accidents",
                "header": "Primi total per Person",
                "item": "TVSH(18%)",
                "type": "text"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "specification": "Personal Accidents",
                "header": "Primi total per Person",
                "item": "Primi Total",
                "type": "text"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

so as you can see there are a couple of groups and each group has items inside, i need to get the group name and show it and than iterate threw items in each group to work with that data.

Comment: I just downvoted this question: it feels like you just want a solution for an issue you didn't confront. You should try to resolve it and show your efforts through a [mcve] for instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested arrays of objects and v-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534249/nested-arrays-of-objects-and-v-for)

Comment: the answer you added as a duplicate is not the same, this is a bad reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
data() {
    return {
        response: {},
    }
},
methods: {
    fetch() {
        axios.get('DATA_URL').then(({response}) => {
            // here is json response of GET request. Assign it to this.response
            this.response = response.data
        })
    }
}
```

```html
<div v-for="(items, title) in response" :key="title">
    <b>{{ title }}</b>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        {{ item.item }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter because it's overwritten `this.response = response`. But I corrected my answer to keep consistency :)

Comment: Sorry for mistake, I corrected my answer: `this.response = response.data`.