# how to make infinite nested loop

Tags: vuejs2

i have a multiple array into array could infinite like

```
['level1', ['level2', ['level3', ['level4']]]]
```

i really don't understand how can i use v-for loop in vue2

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="downline in downlines" :key="downline.id">
            {{ downline.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                downlines: [] //<-- infinite array
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to make infinite `v-for` you got this error ...

[image]

What you exactly need is `v-for` in nested array (I recomend to you rename your question), and in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534249/nested-arrays-of-objects-and-v-for) you can find your answer

Comment: i am sorry let me change  title